# Recommended database/storage for thousands of transactions per second

Tags: c#, database, performance, persistent

I need to be able to insert thousands of transactions per second into some form of storage, and be able to query it quickly.

What I would like to do is log all TCP requests (the key being the source or dest IP Address). 
Then when another requests comes in check if a prior request by the IP is in the store/database/cache and perform the appropriate action.

SQLExpress, SQLCompact, SQLIte, MongoDB, Firebird ? Are any of these fast enough ?

Should I be just use an in memory data structure of some description ?

The store needs to be accessible by multiple threads concurrently...

Any suggestions please...

UPDATE:  RaptorDB ? Is it any good ? Worth considering along with the other Databases/noSQL above ?
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/RaptorDB.aspx

Comment: You're missing one important information: For how long time back will you need to be able to query ? You could have a in-memory datastructure for querying, and maybe writing to disk in batches for history purposes.

Comment: Looking at about 1hr, but it may need 2hrs of data. The network has 1000 pcs on it so a little worried about memory usage on storing 1hr of tcp traffic data in memory.

Comment: This may be more of a question for the Database Administrators Stack Exchange site.

Comment: I'm curious - what are you doing differently if the machine (IP) already made a request versus this being the first request? It sounds as if you are trying to duplicate some functionality that may already exist - please elaborate.

Comment: It records DNS requests and does some fancy stuff regarding redirecting traffic...

Answer (score 0):

At these speeds, your bottleneck is likely to be your disk; a standard SATA drive can do only a few tens of transactions per second. To supplement the disk, throw lots of RAM at it so that the database is stored mostly in memory.

Alternatively, just do it all in memory by rolling your own logger that uses an associative array. Do you need to log ALL data being sent, or just the fact that PC A sent data to PC B?